# How to sync document library with SharePoint Online and Office 2007?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sync

When I try navigate to a document library and click the Sync button in the suite bar I get "The Web Page Cannot Be Displayed" screen and the url starts with "grvopen://".

I'm on Windows 7 64bit with Office 2007.

What do I need in order to sync a document library?  Do I need Groove?  Is there any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing [SkyDrive Pro Client for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=39050) solved my problem